# Posso fazer uma pergunta que já foi respondida no SOen?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Por exemplo, tive um problema e procurei no Google e encontrei a solução facilmente, qualquer um que tiver o problema pode facilmente encontrar uma solução com uma simples pesquisa, porém, essa resposta não está no SOpt.

É certo criar essa pergunta apenas para tê-la na comunidade?

Comment: Pode. Existem muitos tópicos relacionados aqui no meta, alguns deles: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3746/3117, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1072/3117, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125/3117 , http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/735/3117

Comment: Pedro, sim podes! Marquei como duplicada para organizar. O Math sugeriu outras que também são duplicadas/relacionadas.

Comment: Ótimo, obrigado pelo esclarecimento.